# RouterBrowser doesn't redirect to default page on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-functional-component

I have a login page which I want the browser to route to on default. The code I have is doing so for the first run (redirected to http://localhost:3000/login) but after I route to a different page, and hit refresh, it doesn't redirect back to login page, but stays on the last URL it was on. What am I doing wrong?

```
   return (
    <div>
      <h1>Movies - Subscriptions Web Site</h1>
      <br />
      <Link to="/movies" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        <input type="button" value="Movies" />{" "}
      </Link>
      <Link to="/subscriptions" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        <input type="button" value="Subscriptions" />{" "}
      </Link>
      <Link to="/userManagement" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        <input type="button" value="User Management" />{" "}
      </Link>
      <input type="button" value="Log Out" />

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginComp} />
        <Route path="/movies" component={MoviesComp} />
        <Route path="/subscriptions" component={SubscriptionsComp} />
        <Route path="/userManagement" component={ManageUsersComp} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exact` property and `route` tag

```js
<Redirect to="/login" />
```

Comment: I wrote the <Redirect>  before the <Switch> and only that worked. Actually it makes a lot of sense :)   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove exact and route tag and directly write

```
<Redirect path="/" to="/login" />
```

Comment: I wrote the <Redirect>  before the <Switch> and only that worked. Actually it makes a lot of sense :)   Thanks!